# Workspace path is coming in File not found error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run below code snippet in eclipse.

```
Source inputXml = new StreamSource(new File(inputPathname));
        Source xsl = new StreamSource(new File(stylesheetPathname));
        //xsl.setSystemId("SPARK");
        Result outputXml = new StreamResult(new File(outputPathname));

        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
            transformer.setParameter("headingPrefix", "CONFIDENTIAL");
            transformer.setParameter("bodyDisclaimer", "Please do not print!");
            transformer.transform(inputXml, outputXml);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  '/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)'
           :/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
```

May I know please, Any Idea why this workspace path `/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/` is coming in error ?

I'm really kind of stuck in this from last 7-8 hours.

Can any suggest what's wrong going here ..?

Update:

```
"InputXMLPath":"/home/Jon/countries.xml",
"XMLXsltPath":"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl", 
"TransformedXMLOutputPath":"/home/Jon/TransformedXML.xml"
```

These 3 parameters to above code am loading from JSON. And its getting printed with correct values. But in error why its showing with `project path + XML path` ..?

Error Trace:

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  '/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)'
           :/home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: /home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:761)
    at sparkProject.XMLTransformer.xmlProcessor(XMLTransformer.java:22)
    at sparkProject.StartingPoint.main(StartingPoint.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:424)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:479)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:452)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:554)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:947)
    ... 3 more
---------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Jon/eclipse-workspace/spark-app/"/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl" (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:424)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:479)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:452)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:554)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:947)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:761)
    at sparkProject.XMLTransformer.xmlProcessor(XMLTransformer.java:22)
    at sparkProject.StartingPoint.main(StartingPoint.java:22)
```

Comment: Is the correct path `/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl` ? If not, then what is the correct path?

Comment: @Abra, Yes /home/Jon/XSLT.xsl is correct path

Comment: [edit] your question and add code where you assign a value to `stylesheetPathname` (assuming that is meant to contain `/home/Jon/XSLT.xsl`)

Comment: @Abra, Updated question

Comment: Change this line of the code you posted: `e.getMessage()` with `e.printStackTrace()` and then [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Abra, Update Error

Comment: Does the *value* of `XMLXsltPath` *contain* quotation marks?

Comment: The error is in line 22 of file `XMLTransformer.java`. I'm guessing that line is: `Source xsl = new StreamSource(new File(stylesheetPathname));` As I originally wrote, your problem is how you assign a value to `stylesheetPathname` but you have not shown that in your question.

Comment: @nitind, Aha..Eage eye man..! I couldn't even notice it from last whole day..! Thought its coming from JSON and should be fine to use it as it is.  But thanks a alot..! :)